# Repairing Damaged Via & Pad

Tags: soldering, repair

I have damaged a via and the pads that sit on top of that through-hole. Looking at the underside of the PCB, I believe I could just add a single copper wire on the underside and connect it to D69, nice, and that should correct it. However, I ripped off part of the via/through-hole and I'm hoping that I don't need to do anything else other than adding the copper wire for this repair. Should I buy copper wire or could I just use some gauge wire that I already have after removing the jacket? What about the pads? I don't think I can scrap away at the PCB to expose the pads that use to be there.

Yellow markings are the point of interest

Orange would be the copper wire connecting the trace to the pad/via

Top Left: Top-down view of the PCB

Top Right: The switch with the damaged via still connected to the stem of the switch

Bottom: Bottom-up view of the PCB along with where the copper wire should go

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Is there a full row of them? Where does the other ones go on the same pin? If you are lucky, you could just bridge to the next one with wire.

Comment: Thank you! Damn, do you think D69 is toasted / beyond repair? If you look at D67 and D69,  they are exactly the same. One of the stems of the switch goes into that via. So, the copper wire is out then?

Comment: Messure first! What does it go to? I can’t tell for sure from your pictures but it looks like nothing on the outer layers, which leaves you with an inner one.